# Выравнивание ячейки таблицы по центру

Tags: html, css, table

Как сделать выравнивание ячейки таблицы по центру по горизонтали?

Подскажите, как выровнять ячейку с классом `center_top` по центру данной таблицы ? (Можно добавлять классы, но не вынося фразу за пределы синего блока)

```css
.logo_custom {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.logo_text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top: 23px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  color: #F5F5F5;
}

.center_top {
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="body">
  <tr>
    <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
      <center>
        <table align="center" class="container float-center">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table style=" background-color: #386ED9; background-image: url('../assets/img/bg.jpg'); background-position: 50% 50%;
                     background-repeat: no-repeat;  " class="row">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>

                      <th class="small-6 large-6 columns first">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <table class="spacer">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="16" style="font-size:16px;line-height:16px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <img class="logo_custom" src="../assets/img/logo.png" width="153" height="35" alt="text">
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </th>
                      <th class="small-6 large-6 columns last">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <p class="logo_text text-right">View in Browser</p>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <center>
                        <td class="center_top float-center" align="center">
                          <p class="main_text text-center">Dear Customer,</p>
                          <p class="main_subtext text-center">Thank you for choosing our product, the leading mobile parental control software!</p>
                        </td>
                      </center>

                    </tr>

                  </tbody>
                </table>


                <!-- prevent Gmail on iOS font size manipulation -->
                <div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; line-height:0;"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </div>
```

Comment: Это шутка такая?

Comment: Не понял, в чём сарказм?  Проблема в том что в силу обстоятельств не работал хорошо с табличной версткой. А тут есть задача по верстке письма.... Сменой значения свойства display; и установкой alige-item:center; у меня ничего добиться не получилось. Вот собственно и прошу помощи у опытных  разработчиков.

Comment: это точно Вы верстали? В 2020-ом? Я без сарказма, я удивлён просмотрев ваш профиль. Эта вёрстка ужасна и требует другого, более современного подхода. Например, с тегом `<center>` расстались лет 10 назад (к тому же, он стоит в неположенном месте)

Comment: Судя по всему, это верстка email-письма. В 2020-м она все еще должна быть ужасна - пока не вымрет 99% почтовых клиентов, под которые нужно верстать. Что не отменяет, конечно, того, что основы HTML/CSS таки надо знать =)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8&oq=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC

Comment: Если ответить "в лоб", то ячейке `center_top` не хватает св-ва colspan=2

Answer (score 1):

Центрировать надо содержимое внешней ячейки (стилями для нормальных клиентов и браузеров, атрибутами ячейки - для антиквариата).

```css
.centerWrapper {
  height: 300px;
  /* чтобы видеть, как по высоте центрируется тоже */
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.centerWrapper table {
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<table style=" background-color: wheat; width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td class="centerWrapper" align="center" valign="middle">
      <table style=" background-color: #386ED9;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="center_top float-center" align="center">
              <p class="main_text text-center">Dear Customer,</p>
              <p class="main_subtext text-center">Thank you for choosing our product, the leading mobile parental control software!</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```